# Password reset for authlogic

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I am using authlogic for authentication through API

I want to implement if user forgot his password then api send an autogenerated password to user's email account , I don't want to send instructions for password resetting to user email

I am not getting how to update password in database for that user record.

I have tried to reset password this way

```
@user.password = Params[:password]
@user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]
```

I searched alot not getting what exactly it needs to set password this way and I search in [authlogic documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/Password/Methods/InstanceMethods)  but not getting whether these will be helpful for me.

thanks

Comment: Show your code please. We can't help you until you start to help yourself.

Comment: `Params`? Shouldn't that be `params`? I think this is probably some sort of error, even? Is this a copy/paste error, or is this in your code?